# Como omitir un elemento de la lista con el metodo $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que intento hacer es que cargue los elementos del array menos ECUADOR

pero no tengo una idea clara de como hacerlo.

```js
array = [
    {pais: "COLOMBIA", cod: "Co"},
    {pais: "ECUADOR", cod: "Ec"},
    {pais: "ECUADOR BP", cod: "Ec-bp"},
    {pais: "PERU", cod: "Pe"},
    {pais: "PERU DOLARES", cod: "Usd"},
    {pais: "VENEZUELA", cod: "Ve"}
 ]


 $.each(array, function(pos,item){
    
    if(array[1].cod == "Ec"){
        continue;
    }
    var lista = "<option value="+item.cod+"> "+item.pais+" </option>";
        $("#x").append(lista);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas usar la variable `pos` para accesar al valor actual de la iteracion.  Ademas debes usar `return` en lugar de `continue`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
array = [
    {pais: "COLOMBIA", cod: "Co"},
    {pais: "ECUADOR", cod: "Ec"},
    {pais: "ECUADOR BP", cod: "Ec-bp"},
    {pais: "PERU", cod: "Pe"},
    {pais: "PERU DOLARES", cod: "Usd"},
    {pais: "VENEZUELA", cod: "Ve"}
 ]


 $.each(array, function(pos,item){
    
    if(array[pos].cod == "Ec"){
        return;
    }
    var lista = "<option value="+item.cod+"> "+item.pais+" </option>";
        $("#x").append(lista);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="x"></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usa `return` en lugar de `continue`. Ten en cuenta que estamos en una función, no en un bucle. Lo que hacemos es llamar a la función con cada elemento del array.

Por otro lado, no necesitas hacer `array[1].cod`, porque estás haciendo una iteracion por cada elemento. Usa `item`, que es el elemento que estás recorriendo.

Además, `array[1].cod` siempre será `== "Ec"`, porque es el elemento en el índice 1.

Algo así quedaría:

```js
array = [
    {pais: "COLOMBIA", cod: "Co"},
    {pais: "ECUADOR", cod: "Ec"},
    {pais: "ECUADOR BP", cod: "Ec-bp"},
    {pais: "PERU", cod: "Pe"},
    {pais: "PERU DOLARES", cod: "Usd"},
    {pais: "VENEZUELA", cod: "Ve"}
 ]

 $.each(array, function(pos, item) {
    if(item.cod == "Ec") {
        return;
    }
    var lista = "<option value="+item.cod+"> "+item.pais+" </option>";
    $("#x").append(lista);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="x"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto otra forma de realizar esto. Puedes utilizar la función `map` de javascript para crear un arreglo con los elementos `option` del select.

**Options con una sola condición**: Si se cumple la condición `el.cod != 'Ec'` entonces se retorna el option, de lo contrario se retorna vacío. Luego se unen con la función `join`.

**Options validando con indexOf**: Agregue otro escenario en donde puedes utilizar la variable `skip` para colocar los códigos que se deseen omitir en la lista. Esta validación se lleva a cabo con la función indexOf. `skip.indexOf(el.cod) < 0`

Igualmente, te compartí la versión utilizando solamente javascript y otra con jQuery.

```js
array = [
    {pais: "COLOMBIA", cod: "Co"},
    {pais: "ECUADOR", cod: "Ec"},
    {pais: "ECUADOR BP", cod: "Ec-bp"},
    {pais: "PERU", cod: "Pe"},
    {pais: "PERU DOLARES", cod: "Usd"},
    {pais: "VENEZUELA", cod: "Ve"}
 ]


// Options con una sola condición
let options = array
  .map((el)=> el.cod != 'Ec' ? `<option value="${el.cod}">${el.pais}</option>` : '')
  .join('');
 
// Options validando con indexOf
skip = ['Ec', 'Ec-bp'];

let options2 = array
  .map((el)=> skip.indexOf(el.cod) < 0 ? `<option value="${el.cod}">${el.pais}</option>` : '')
  .join('');

// Versión sin jQuery
document.getElementById('nojquery').innerHTML = options;

// Versión con jQuery
$('#jquery').append(options2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>No jQuery</h2>
<select id="nojquery"></select>
<h2>jQuery</h2>
<select id="jquery"></select>
```